# Error in install the Force.com IDE in Eclipse-jee-juno

Tags: force.com

I am trying to install Force.com plugin 27.0 version not 28.0 in "eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32 , But i am getting this error

"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Force.com IDE 27.0.0.201302151147 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 27.0.0.201302151147)
  Missing requirement: Force.com IDE 27.0.0.201302151147 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 27.0.0.201302151147) requires "

I tried everything installed the "org.eclipse.update.ui_3.2.300.v20100512" also in plugin folder but no help can anyone suggest me anything,, and how to install the   Force.com plugin 27.0 from the marketplace I am not getting the option of  Force.com plugin 27.0 from marketplace install wizard.

I have already spend lots of time to dig this but no help Please tell me somthing usefull

Thanks in advance
Raman

Answer (score 1):

Very long post with suggestions here: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Install-Eclipse-Juno-4-2-with-Force-com-IDE/td-p/462323

SFDC doc http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation states highest supported Eclipse is 3.6 (which is what I use)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Force.com eclipse plugin with "Install New Software Wizard", and then add org.eclipse.update.ui_3.2.300.v20100512 jars to plugin folder. 
Worked for me on Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

- Go to Help | Install New Software | Available Software Sites then click Add... 
  Name: Eclipse 3.8 Update Site, 
  Location: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8
- make sure it's selected and hit ok
- Click Add.. (on the Help | Install New Software screen) then use 
  Name: Force.com IDE, 
  Location: http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/

Then You should be able to install normally and eclipse will fetch all dependant files from 3.8 version.
That works fine also with Force IDE 28.* and Eclipse Kepler

Keep in mind that **this configuration is not supported by SFDC**